# Selecting Template and theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a panel and allow user to select a template and a theme for their website just like in

> http://members.webs.com/s/signup/?churchSignup=1

But i dont know what they have used.Can you please tell me what is it or suggest me some alternative of it?.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique names for each template and link them together in the database. You can then perform a while-loop to show them on the website. If you are only interested in the jQuery, you can combine Ajax with jQuery to select the specific template.

I suppose you are already working on the code by yourself?

Comment: Yes i am working on the code by myself.But doesnt jQuery have anything like this as an already built feature?